# How to get Flare elements?

Tags: unity, c#

Is it possible to get the elements or the textures of a Flare and to change them at runtime? If so, then how do I get them?

Pseudocode:

```
Flare flare = GetComponent<Flare>();
foreach (Element e in flare) {
    e.Size = 10;
    e.Color = Color.green;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Flare.html), you can't edit a flare at runtime, only in the inspector :

> ### Flare
>
> **Description**
>
> A flare asset. Read more about flares in the components reference.
>
> **The flare class has no properties. It needs to be setup up in the inspector.** You can reference flares and assign them to a Light at runtime.

```
    // Drag & Drop the flare assets here
    public Flare[] Flares;
    private LensFlare lensFlare;

    protected void Start()
    {
        // Supposing you have a LensFlare component attached
        lensFlare = GetComponent<LensFlare>();
        lensFlare.flare = Random.Range(0, Flares.Length) ;
    }
```